# Making the items of a WearableListView repeatable

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, wear-os

With Android's lesson on creating lists for wearable devices (http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/wearables/ui/lists.html), I was wondering how to create a "repeatable" list of items just like the alarm clock app as follows:

[image]

... How can I make my WearableListItemLayout move back towards the beginning of the list of items if I were to either scroll up or down continuously as depicted above?

Thanks!

**EDIT (based on Budius's post):**

Here's my newly incorporated main activity:

```
public class DimensionsActivity extends Activity implements WearableListView.ClickListener {

    // Sample dataset for the list
    private String[] elements = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dimensions);

        // Get the list component from the layout of the activity
        WearableListView listView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.wearable_list);

        // Assign an adapter to the list
        listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, elements));

        // Set a click listener
        listView.setClickListener(this);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            listView.scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2); // adjust this value as needed
        }
    }

    // WearableListView click listener
    @Override
    public void onClick(WearableListView.ViewHolder v) {
        Integer tag = (Integer) v.itemView.getTag();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTopEmptyRegionClick() {}

    // The adapter populates the WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener element with content.
    // The following simple adapter populates the list with elements based on an array of strings:
    private static final class Adapter extends WearableListView.Adapter {
        private String[] mDataset;
        private final Context mContext;
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
        public Adapter(Context context, String[] dataset) {
            mContext = context;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mDataset = dataset;
        }

        // Provide a reference to the type of views you're using
        public static class ItemViewHolder extends WearableListView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView textView;
            public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                // find the text view within the custom item's layout
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            }
        }

        // Create new views for list items
        // (invoked by the WearableListView's layout manager)
        @Override
        public WearableListView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Inflate our custom layout for list items
            return new ItemViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null));
        }

        // Replace the contents of a list item
        // Instead of creating new views, the list tries to recycle existing ones
        // (invoked by the WearableListView's layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(WearableListView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            position = Integer.MAX_VALUE % position; // offset the position to be within your range

            // retrieve the text view
            ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            TextView view = itemHolder.textView;
            // replace text contents
            view.setText(mDataset[position]);
            // replace list item's metadata
            holder.itemView.setTag(position);
        }

        // Return the size of your dataset
        // (invoked by the WearableListView's layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

... And then I end up with the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of getting real continuous list, but there's a tricky I've applied before on our app that works nicely.

You just make it right in the middle of a really really long list. For that you use a `WearableListView` on the adapter `getItemCount()` you return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and during `onCreate()` you move the list to the middle.

Like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ... all the good to build views and setup the WearableListView

   if(savedInstanceState == null) {
      wearableListView.scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2); // adjust this value as needed
   }
}
```

on the adapter:

```
public int getItemCount() {
   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

public void bindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
   position = position % mDataset.length; // offset the position to be within your range

   ... proceed with the normal position view binding

}
```

I remember on the view that we used this tricky on the app I worked, we did the math and a user would have to scroll through several and several hours until it reaches the beginning (or the end) of the adapter

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't really understand the math behind it to be honest lol but I gave it a try as shown above in my edited post! Any ideas on what I did wrong to get an out of index error?

Comment: I typed all this by heart, I guess my error is on `position = Integer.MAX_VALUE % position`. The symbol `%` gives the remainder of the integer division of one by the other. So the remainder of any big number divided by 12 (to use in a clock) will always be between `0~11`, so the binding happen in a correct position of your actual dataset.